# brackets around formGroup break route in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am running into an issue when I add brackets around formGroup like:

```
<form [formGroup]="create_module" (ngSubmit)="save(create_module.value)" class="form-validate mb-lg" action="POST">
```

When I have the brackets there I cannot load the route. No errors or anything, it goes to default route if I try loading via url or doesn't do anything from link.

Also the form is not submitting properly. It performs and GET submission instead of letting the component manage it.

Here is a look at my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.scss']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
  private create_module: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.create_module = fb.group({
      'name':[null,Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  save(input):void{
    console.log(input);
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? Why does having the brackets break my route?

**Update:**
Also noticed same behavior happens when I have brackets around [formControl]

Comment: How do you got to another route? What is `action="POST"` supposed to do?

Comment: ng-cli refreshes when I make code changes and sends me to default route if I have brackets. The action="POST" is me trying to override the behavior. it has no effect one way or another. Disregard.

Comment: Try adding `<button type="button">xxx</button>` to the form

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this will not trigger (ngSubmit)

Comment: What do you need `(ngSubmit)` for? `<button type="button" (click)="save(create_module.value)">xxx</button>` should do the same

Comment: You can also try `<form [formGroup]="create_module" (ngSubmit)="save(create_module.value);false"` instead of the button

Comment: Ok, but the question states that brackets around [formGroup] break the route. So I cannot even get to the form.

Comment: I just try to make sense of your question. Until now it doesn't. The only guess is that it's related to submit, but your question doesn't contain any information how form and route are related.

Comment: If I have a link that when clicked goes to this form, if I have brackets around formGroup, that link does nothing. No errors, nothing. If I remove the brackets and just keep formGroup="save(create_module.value)", the link works. Also when angular-cli refreshes from the changes it takes me to the default route. Why?

Comment: What if you add the for to `AppComponent` (just for testing purposes) so routing is not involved. Do you have `ReactiveForms` module imported in the module that contains `CreateComponent`?

Comment: Then the page is blank, no errors. nothing loads

Comment: @JasonSpick Could you create a plunker with your code? :)